# UIAlert not showing

Tags: ios, uialertview

Fresh and green newbie here. I just started programming and already got stuck with UIAlert. I've searched on this site but there are so many postings and as I said I am kinda new to all this so I don't know what to really look for. This is what I have.

```
-(void)showError {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@"Please try again later. Have a nice day."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

Comment: You need to call `[alert show];` if you want to actually show the alert.

Comment: Please read the docs for `UIAlertView` before posting a question like this.

Comment: Did you searched it; even in SO? Because there are so many of UIAlertView questions and answer. And follow @rmaddy's suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[alert show];

I always forget this too. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Need to do

```
[alert show];
```

to present

Answer (score 1):

Code should be :

```
-(void)showError {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@"Please try again later. Have a nice day."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-(void)showError 
{

```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:@"Please try again later. Have a nice day."
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

   [alert show];
```

}